# Make httpwebrequest with "burn" CPU

Tags: c#

I want to run about 10,000 concurrent requests, using .net HttpWebRequest, not all of them going to the same host and some of them go through a pool of proxies.

I'm currently using Threads, which works fine up to 1000 concurrent, but then my CPU load 100%. How to fix it?

```
public string HttpGet(string url)
{
    try {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Timeout = 20000;
        request.CookieContainer = Cookie;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return tmp;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I send request each time, so make 1000 requests for 1 minute.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Adjust the title of your question and provide more useful information. Threads code, CPU details, what kind of requests, etc. Read and meet the guidelines:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use async tasks instead of threads. I/O operations don't need thread tho wait for them, but OS spends time on switching between them.
2. Use `using` blocks instead of `Close` call to properly dispose resources even if request fails.
3. Don't forget to set correct maximum limit for concurrent requests.
4. `catch (Exception ex)` is an antipattern.